# How to initiate new chat in MS teams using graph API

Tags: microsoft-teams

I can send/reply to an existing chat thread, but can not send a message to someone whom does not have any established chats yet

I am using this POST API - 
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{ID}/chats/messages
and getting this error 
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "72bb5b10-7268-4014-9e87-0f5f685d4184",
            "date": "2019-10-03T07:50:54"
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

Currently there are no API's to start a conversation in 1:1 scope. If you want to create a new chat thread in a team please take a look at [Create chatMessage in a channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http). Please let us know if you need any further assistance.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I have implemented the functionality - "initiate a new chat thread in teams". 
Now my requirement is to initiate a new chat thread in chat window, is there any work around for this ?

Comment: Initiating a chat in a personal chat window is currently not supported. You can try [deeplinking to a user's chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deep-links#generating-a-deep-link-to-a-chat) and send a message through chat.

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT, has there been any changes to this?  Is there a beta API yet?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Based on documentation you can now create new chats through the Graph API
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

You can also test it out in the Graph Explorer https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer